# render table with correct for loops

Tags: angular

I have an array as following:

```
public products: any = [
{title: 'Product_1', desc: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry', img: '../assets/prod_1.jpg', property_1: 50, property_2: 6, property_3: 0, property_4: 76, property_5: 54, property_6: 87, property_7: 0},
{title: 'Product_2', desc: 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s', img: '../assets/prod_2.jpg', property_1: 0, property_2: 0, property_3: 65, property_4: 0, property_5: 0, property_6: 7, property_7: 88},
{title: 'Product_3', desc: 'It has survived not only five centuries but also the leap into electronic typesetting', img: '../assets/prod_3.jpg', property_1: 0, property_2: 97, property_3: 0, property_4: 56, property_5: 0, property_6: 0, property_7: 86},
{title: 'Product_4', desc: ' It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing,', img: '../assets/prod_4.jpg', property_1: 90, property_2: 25, property_3: 56, property_4: 64, property_5: 0, property_6: 98, property_7: 0},
]
```

And I am trying to render a table from it as following:

```
<table>
  <ng-template let-product ngFor [ngForOf]="products">

    <td>
      <h5>{{product.title}}</h5>
      <img src="{{product.img}}" height="200" width="300" border="1">
      <h6>{{product.desc}}</h6>
    </td>

  </ng-template>
</table>
```

This works however this is not how I want it. I want to display it as following:

[image]

How can I write my ngFor loops to achieve this?

Comment: Your number of key is dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
<table *ngIf="keyList && products">
  <ng-template let-product ngFor [ngForOf]="products">
    <td>
      <h5>{{product.title}}</h5>
      <img src="{{product.img}}" height="200" width="300" border="1">
      <h6>{{product.desc}}</h6>
    </td>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let key of keyList" >
   <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let item of products">
        {{item[key]}}
    </td>
   </tr>
 </ng-container>
</table>
```

with:

```
this.keyList= Object.keys(this.products[0])
this.keyList.splice(this.keyList.indexOf('title'),1)
this.keyList.splice(this.keyList.indexOf('desc'),1)
this.keyList.splice(this.keyList.indexOf('img'),1)
```

Comment: using const key throws me an error as ngFor isn't known property of td and if I replace it with let then basically nothing is rendered

Comment: Thanks for your approach though, I figured it out how can I further go about it. Also, using const throws an error even from the updated answer. So I used let and `<tr *ngFor="let key of keyList">
        <td><h6>Property 1</h6></td>
        <td *ngFor="let item of products">
          {{item.property_1}}
        </td>
      </tr>`

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/yditsYYiacAFy8Keu155/ 
But if the first item of your list have less keys than other row, the other keys will miss